# Magento: list all values of a single attribute

Tags: magento, attributes, mage

I'm trying to list up all the existing values of a newly created attribute in magento 1.7.0.2. 
(and make them clickable links, so that on click they list up all of the items with the specific attribute value, but that's not a priority right now)

The attribute code is "artist"

So far i created the file Artist.php in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/ with the following code:

```
public function getAllArtists()
{
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
    ->setEntityTypeFilter($product->getResource()->getTypeId())
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'artist');
$attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($product->getResource());
$artists = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
  return $artists;  
}
```

and the file artist.phtml in /app/design/frontend/default/template-name/template/catalog/product with this code:

```
 <ul id="artist_list">
  <?php foreach ($this->getAllArtists() as $artist): ?> 
  <li><a href="<?php Mage::getURL() ?>catalogsearch/advanced/result/?&artist;[]=<?php echo $artist['value'] ?>&search;="><?php echo $artist['label'] ?></a></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
```

which i then call in a static block with

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/artist.phtml"}}
```

but nothing appears...

i used the code from this thread: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/19982/P0/

the attribute is set "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end"
and i call the attribute value of each item in the ../template/product/view.phtml with

```
<?php echo $_product->getData('artist') ?>
```

and it correctly displays the value.

any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
    $name='whatever_your_attribute_name';
    $attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($name)->getFirstItem();
    $attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
    $attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); 
    print_r($attributeOptions);
```

Ref: [Magento - get all attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043690/magento-get-all-attribute-value)

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful to load model by id here if attribute values were set from admin panel

Answer (score 1):

it will be just

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute(4,'artist');
if($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
    foreach($options as $key=>$value) {
        if(count($value)==2) {
            $artists[] = $value['label'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still not working.. 
i replaced the code in public function with yours and it still wont display anything. 
i am a noob in php, i have to say too

Comment: Ah, in static block you should use block type = catalog/artist

Comment: here is what i got sofar: 
Artist.php contains the following:
    
`public function getAllArtists()
    {
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute(4,'artist');if($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
    foreach($options as $key=>$value) {
        if(count($value)==2) {
            $artist[] = $value['label'];
        }
    }
}
}`

Comment: the artist.phtml contains 

`<ul id="artist_list">
  <?php foreach ($this->getAllArtists() as $artist): ?> 
   <li><a href="<?php Mage::getURL() ?>catalogsearch/advanced/result/?&artist;[]=<?php echo $artist['value'] ?>&search;="><?php echo $artist['label'] ?></a></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>`

Comment: and in the static bock: 
`{{block type="catalog/artist" template="catalog/product/artist.phtml"}}`

Comment: ok, after another try i got "syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC error"
so i edited the "public" in public function out and now i get this error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Artist' not found

Comment: ok - you also probably lost "return $artist;" at the end of function

Comment: as for Class 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Artist' - you can just place  your file at   app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/

Comment: `class Mage_Catalog_Block_Artist
{ 
 public function getAllArtists() { 
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute(4,'artist');
if($attribute->usesSource‌​()) { 
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
 foreach($options as $key=>$value) { 
if(count($value)==2) { $artist[] = $value['label']; }
 } 
} 
return $artist; 
} 

}`

Comment: ok, using the code above in Artist.php, it still nothing shows up. also, my firebug tells me that the static block doesn't get called. maybe that has something to do with it

Comment: if you had an error - Class 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Artist' not found - previously - it means that this block was called.

Comment: well then something must went wrong somewhere else, but where?
maybe could you please explain how your code works?