# Magento - get all attribute value

Tags: magento

It is necessary for me to get a list of all the meanings an attribute of “color”. when i use this code

```
$name='color';
$attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($name)->getFirstItem();
$attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
```

In that case I get that kind of list:

```
 (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [value] => 6
                [label] => blueAdmin
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [value] => 5
                [label] => coralAdmin
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [value] => 3
                [label] => redAdmin
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [value] => 4
                [label] => limeAdmin
            )
    )
```

It is the list of all meanings which are displayed in administration's part of website. How can I get a list of all meanings of attributes which are displayed in the shop not in administration's part of website?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the attribute option values for a particular store by setting the store ID on the attribute prior to calling getAllOptions(), e.g.,

```
$attributeOptions = $attribute->setStoreId(1)->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
```

gets the option values for the store with ID 1. You can get the ID of the current store with

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
```

So something like this should get you what you want:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$attributeOptions = $attribute->setStoreId($storeId)->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
```